# Is there some example of that the dimension of every fiber bigger than the relative dimension?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In exercise (II.3.22(b)) of Hartshorne's *Algebraic Geometry* [1],
there is a proposition:

Let $f\colon X \rightarrow Y$ be a dominant
morphism of integral schemes of finite type over a field $k$.
Let $e=\operatorname{dim} X-\operatorname{dim} Y$ be the relative
dimension of $X$ over $Y$. For any point $y \in f(X)$, show that
every irreducible component of the fibre $X_{y}$ has dimension
$\geqslant e$.

**Question:  Is there some example of a morphism $f\colon X\to Y$ such that the dimension of every fiber $X_y$ of $f$ is $> e$.**

<sup>[1]: Hartshorne, Robin, Algebraic geometry, Graduate Texts in Mathematics. 52. New York-Heidelberg-Berlin: Springer-Verlag. XVI, 496 p. DM 53.30; $ 26.65 (1977). [ZBL0367.14001](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0367.14001).</sup>

Comment: Isn't it true that for generic $y$ the dimension $=e$?

Comment: @markvs Indeed, by part c of said exercise.

Comment: @yearning4pi: So what's the problem?

Comment: @yearning4pi Would you care to record this below so the question can be marked as answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In part c of this exercise, i.e. II.3.22(c) in Hartshorne *Algebraic Geometry*, the reader is asked to show that there exists a dense open subset $U$ of $X$ such that for any $y\in f(U)$ we have $\dim U_y=e$. Since $U$ is in particular nonempty, this means that no example exists where the dimensions of all of the fibers are $>e$.

Note that the argument works without the hypothesis that $X$ and $Y$ are of finite-type over a field $k$. We just need $f$ to be of finite-type, and we take $e$ to be the transcendence degree of $K(X)$ over $K(Y)$.